# Reference Not Responsive

Tags: references

I had contacted a former boss via email a week ago who happily agreed to be my reference for a job I am applying to. However, I just received an email today from my potential employer that he has never heard back from my former boss about a reference. Though I have already given out another reference, I am really confused now and wonder if I should contact my former boss about it.

Comment: One week isn't exactly a lot of time. Your former boss may have been out sick or on vacation? They did not agree to be on stand-by 24/7. I never understood that personal reference system. What if my former boss is unavailable, does that mean I'm not as good a worker? Never made sense to me.

Comment: Yes, contact him now (even if you have another reference, having the initial reference call them back would be better for you). Ideally, you should have contacted your former boss as soon as you gave out their contact information to give them a heads up. Also, contact the new reference you gave to give that person a heads up as well.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you obtain the reference and deliver it, not expect your former boss to contact direct on your behalf. You have the most at stake and it's your application. Perhaps they had trouble contacting your old boss.

Either way it's your responsibility to come up with a reference, you should write this down to experience. If you feel wronged then make a mental note that your former boss is unreliable in matters like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already shared a new reference but just couldn't understand why my old boss didn't respond to my potential employer. I thought of him as a very helpful and enthusiastic person. I would definitely write this down to experience.

Comment: Some employers insist on contacting the reference provider directly to avoid any possible interference with the document.

Comment: @SolarMike yep, I covered that scenario in the answer